# jsp:include gives 404 when running

Tags: java, jsp, include

My directory tree is like this,

```
- /index.jsp
- /template/topHeader.jsp
- /accounts/signin.jsp
```

In my `index.jsp` I have included the `topHeader.jsp` like this,

```
<jsp:include page="template/topHeader.jsp" />
```

This works fine without any problem. But in the `topHeader.jsp` I have some `<a>` tags which I have given paths,

```
<div class="pull-left">
    Hello! <a href="../accounts/signin.jsp">Sign in</a>.
</div>
```

After running, this link gives a 404 which is understandable because the index page is already in the root folder. Now in the future I may have to include this `topHeader.jsp` almost everywhere.

Browser changes the url like this,

```
localhost:8084/project/index.jsp
```

after clicking on the sign in (404)

```
localhost:8084/accounts/signin.jsp
```

but the path should be

```
localhost:8084/project/accounts/signin.jsp
```

I have also tried including the `topHeader.jsp` in the following way, but got the same results.

```
<%@ include file="template/topHeader.jsp" %>
```

So what is the easiest way to give the paths to `<a>` tags. I'm sorry the question may seem a bit unclear but I don't know how to explain it better.

Comment: you can give paths starting from your root directory..

Comment: thats what I have done. as the topHeader is in a folder I have inserted `../`. but the `index.jsp` is already in the root.

Comment: If I enter the path without `../` it would work. but what happens in the future if I have to include it in another jsp in a folder.

Comment: you said `After running, this link gives a 404 which is understandable because the index page is already in the root folder` . This is not the case at all . When you give paths to anything (an anchor in your case ), this path is relative to the file in which you have given paths i.e. topheader.jsp in this case.

Comment: So if a 404 error is occurring there might be some other reason

Comment: @Gaur93 check now. I have edited the question

Comment: try to use jstl tags for urls <c:url value='/accounts/signin.jsp'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` to give relative paths to the links,

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/accounts/signin.jsp">Sign in</a>
```